# Uploading with Carrierwave to both :file and :fog

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

Is it possible to upload with Carrierwave to both `:file` storage and `:fog` storage?

Something like:

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
   storage :file, :fog
   ...
end
```

Thanks